# Filtering Fullcalendar events based on additional ID parameter

Tags: php, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I am using the jQuery library [Fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) to display events for sports teams from a MYSQL database. I have managed to properly setup a JSON feed which displays all the events in the database.

However, a coach can administrate up to three teams, and each of these teams have their own page with its own calendar. Currently, all events are listed in all calendars. I need some sort of filter to make sure that only events belonging to the right team is displayed in each calendar.

I have given each team a unique URL based on their ID, like this.

```
http://localhost/master/index.php/team/56
```

The JSON feed currently outputs this:

```
{"id":"14","event_id":"8","team":"56","start":"2013-12-16 18:00:00","title":"Mandagsgym","description":"Ivar er trenar","location":"Haukelandshallen","start_time":"18:00:00","end_time":"20:00:00"}
```

My current jQuery:

```
var filter_id = $('#filter_id').val(); //a variable with the team ID, 
                                       fetched from a hidden input field

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    firstDay:'1',
    defaultView: 'basicWeek',
    height: 400,
    editable: true,
    weekends: false,
    header: 
    {
        left: '',
        center: '',
        right: 'prev,next, month,basicWeek'
    },
    columnFormat: 'ddd d/M',
    allDayDefault: false,
    events: 
    {
        url: 'http://localhost/master/index.php/team/json'
    }
    });
```

As I see it, I have two options: 
1) Find a way to assign the third segment of the URL (the team ID) to the JSON feed PHP function, hence providing the calendars with dynamic JSON feeds.

2) Fetch the team ID from the URL, assign it to a Javascript variable and then do some filtering using the Fullcalendar methods, removing or at least hiding the events from the calendar where the team ID does not match the team ID in the URL.

Both of these proposed approaches are well beyond my relatively limited knowledge. I personally fancy approach nr.2. I would be absolutely delighted if anyone could come up with a solution, as I've been stuck on this problem for days.

Comment: If I were in your shoes I would definetly add a parameter to the php call. At this point it is not clear which kind of routing you are using nor did you show us the php function which retrieves the data. Imo you could just add a get parameter to the url         url: 'http://localhost/master/index.php/team/json?team_id=' + filter_id;
 and retrive that trough $_GET['team_id']; within your php file

Comment: Option 1 makes more sense. You don't need the two other teams' data, so why return it to the client? Not a huge issue now, but if you have 100 teams it will be.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, guys. Upon reflection, this does indeed seem as the better solution and although I will stick with alternative 2 for now, I will look for a better solution at a later point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think option two is easiest but not necessarily the best.  Use a custom events function to filter your results by team_id and then pass the filtered results to the calendar like this:

```
events: function(start,end, callback) {
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/master/index.php/team/json', function(data){
        var eventsToShow = [];
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            if(data[i].team == filter_id){
                eventsToShow.push(data[i]);
            }
        }
        callback(eventsToShow);
    });
}
```

In my use of fullcalendar, I use a custom function for the events, but my json feed is also dynamic so that I can specify which users to fetch events for.  This allows for a pretty dynamic calendar.

Comment: Shade, this function worked perfectly, thank you for your help. As cptnk and Mike pointed out in the comments above, option 1 is probably the most performance-friendly and I will keep looking for such a solution. However, your answerdid indeed solve my problem and will be marked as the right answer.